# MediaWiki: How to display a link only if the page exists

Tags: mediawiki

I'd like to display a link (or an image) only if the page exists. What is the mediawiki syntax for doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the function `#ifexist`
 http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions

```
{{#ifexist: page title | value if exists | value if doesn't exist }}
```

Comment: Thanks! My final syntax for showing an image only if it exists and leaving a blank space otherwise was `{{#ifexist: File:{{PAGENAME}}.png | [[File:{{PAGENAME}}.png|frameless|700px]] | }}`